# Fixed position property

Tags: html, css

When working with fixed position property, to keep a nav bar positioned at all times in mobile function i faced some problems during the trials and erros. However with margin top's and translation fuctions it is now fixed and looks clean.

Are there more ways to get this done?

In my believe this means that a page ( where the CSS ) is worked in with that rule-set, that it is always viewed as the first box. Is that a correct viewpoint, or am i missing something on this property and how it works?

Edit : As requested i have edited my codes in here.

```
.leftNav{
    top: 0%;
    transform: translateX(0%);
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 80px;
    background: linear-gradient(
        to left,
        rgba(2, 2, 2, 0.95),
        rgba(21, 22, 22, 0.95)
      );
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

That's basically my CSS right here, i used the TranslateX to let myself know at what point i changed the position.

```
<div class="leftNav">
        <div class="logo">

            <a href="#"> <img src="./facebook.png" alt="just-a-logo"></a>
</div>
        </div>
```

In this part are my HTML lines. I devided the nav into two sections, considering i wanted to keep one part for my logo and posible other inputs laters on, the other i used for Hamburger menu.

```
.introPage{
    margin-top: 80px;
    height: 91.7vh;
    background: rgb(233, 227, 224);
}
```

This is basically the ending to keep the nav-bar up, so it fixes it up for the fixed positioned part.

Comment: Can you provide your HTML and CSS?

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I changed it now, and put in the codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the sticky propertry to fix it in the top. But note:

```css
.nav-bar
{
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  /*
  The sticky position is a position between fixed and static.
  It is in its original place until you scroll over it.
  But, th sticky in this case will not work, because its parent,
  that is the div is not having the sticky property.
  */
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0 !important;
}
section
{
  height: 400vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <nav class="nav-bar">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Mail</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <section>
    Scroll.........................................................
    Scroll.........................................................
    Scroll.........................................................
  </section>
</body>
```

So, you should make the sticky property to the parent element, but not the body tag. See this:

```css
.nav-bar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  /*
  This will work. The sticky property keeps the nav always top.
  */
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  border: 2px solid black;
  /*
  Increase the value of the z-index to keep the nav bar above all the contents.
  */
  z-index: 7;
}


/*
Increase the heigth of the section to let you scroll down.
*/

section {
  height: 400vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="font-size: 7em;">
    The Headding!
  </div>
  <div class="nav-bar">
    <nav>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Mail</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <section>
  </section>
</body>
```

So sticky might be useful than fixed

Comment: This is indeed a very good solution. I found that one also on W3Schools, but unfortunately i did not understand correctly that you can change the position of the scrolling to the top-part, i thought it had to go by it first. But i now noticed that with this example it is indeed posible to use sticky. Thanks for sharing.